# Basis of Vector space $\Bbb C$ over rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

What will be the basis of vector space $\Bbb C$ over a field of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$?

I think it will be an infinite basis! I think it will be $B=\{r_1+r_2i \mid  r_1,  r_2 \in \Bbb Q^{c}\}\cup\{1,i\}$. But this generator is an uncountable set. Can a basis of a vector space be that big? If it is true does it mean that $\Bbb Q$-module (Vector space) $\Bbb C$ is free?

Comment: Any vector space is a free module over its field, though the set you wrote isn't a basis: for example, it contains both $\pi$ and $2\pi$, which are linearly dependent.

Comment: as for being free, does $\mathbb{C}$ have torsion?

Comment: @IgorRivin: how does that relate to being free? I mean, a module which is not torsion-free can't be free, but the converse is far from true.

Comment: @tomasz it is not equivalent, but it is related. The OP has to start somewhere.

Comment: @tomasz and the two ARE equivalent in the f.g. case.

Comment: but C is not finitely generated.

Comment: @RyanReich Then how will be construct a basis for it?

Comment: The phrase "the basis" is misleading: in general, vector spaces don't have any distinguished basis; there are multiple bases and no special way a priori to choose one. No $(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)+i(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$ is not a basis for $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$; as mentioned it is not linearly independent. Yes a basis for $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$ will be infinite (indeed, the same size as $\Bbb R$). Vector space bases can be any size whatsoever, no limit. Every vector space is a free module over its base field. In general there is no constructive way to create bases for spaces.

Comment: The best question towards hinting a proof that axiom of choice may be wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note first that for any ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$, if the cardinality $\lvert M\rvert$ is infinite and greater than $\lvert R \rvert$, then any generating set of $M$ (in particular, any basis) must have cardinality equal to $\lvert M\rvert$ (this is simple combinatorics).

In particular, any basis of $\bf C$ over $\bf Q$ must have cardinality of the continuum, which is rather uncountable no matter how you look at it.

Secondly, any module over a field (i.e. any vector space) is free (it's a basic theorem in linear algebra that every vector space has a basis, assuming axiom of choice).

On the other hand, in ZF alone (without axiom of choice), it is consistent that $\bf C$ has no basis over $\bf Q$ (because such a basis can't be measurable, and there are models of ZF where every set is measurable). Therefore, loosely speaking, you can't write down such a basis. A little more precisely, it's impossible to write a formula which will provably define a basis of $\bf C$ over $\bf Q$ without some strong set-theoretic assumptions like $V=L$.

The set you've written down certainly generates $\bf C$ as a vector space, but it's not hard to see that it is not linearly independent.

Comment: What is ZF in the second part?

Comment: Does it implies that $\Bbb Q$- module $\Bbb C$ is not free?? And what about $\Bbb Z$- module $\Bbb C$??? Is it also not free. Is it necessary that there should be a basis to say that it is free module?

Comment: @PittHarmanN-FreshmaN: The Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.

Comment: @MatHeMatCian: No. In general (that is, assuming ZFC), every vector space has a basis, as I have said. It's just that in many cases the basis can't be written down explicitly, we can only show that it exists. A free module is by definition one which has a basis, at least that's the definition I know.

Comment: @tomasz That is a big name, I never heard it before. but its always nice to get to know new things. I will google Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. Anyways thanks a lot dear tomasz.

Comment: @MatHeMatCian: Oh, and I forgot your second question. The complex numbers are a divisible group, and free ${\bf Z}$-modules are never divisible (the basis elements are not divisible), so no, ${\bf C}$ is not a free ${\bf Z}$-module.

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward answer for "what is a basis for $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$" is that we don't know.  The sneaky answer is that we do know there is one, because any maximal linearly independent set is a basis, and exists by Zorn's Lemma.  This shows that $\mathbb{C}$ is a free $\mathbb{Q}$-module, since that concept is literally equivalent to the existence of a basis, and the same argument in fact proves that any vector space is a free module over its field.  As noted in the comments, for *finite-dimensional* vector spaces one could deduce this from the fact that fields are PIDs and their modules are torsion-free, but that uses a very fancy theorem of ring theory that, moreover, reduces to computing a basis!  So it's enough just to say that we could, in principle, find one.

As for *how* you would find one, the answer is not satisfying.  One way is by ordinal induction: for every ordinal $\alpha$ less than the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$, suppose we have found a $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent set in $\mathbb{C}$ of cardinality that of $\alpha$.  If it doesn't span $\mathbb{C}$, then it can be extended by some new element and that gives such a set for $\alpha + 1$.  For any limit ordinal $\beta$, construct the union of the linearly independent sets for lesser $\alpha$, which is linearly independent since they are, by construction, nested.  Then by the time we pass through all ordinals less than or equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$, we must have found a basis, since we will have run out of complex numbers!

I do not encourage you to actually implement this construction.

Comment: Is it true in the case of $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb C$? I mean, is it free? Where Z is not field.

Comment: No, it's not a free abelian group, because it's completely divisible, which is never the case when a basis exists (how would you express half a basis vector?)

Comment: Could you please elaborate it little more. What do you mean by completely divisible.

Comment: Google "divisible group".

Comment: Are you talking about $\Bbb C$ when you say abelian group?

Comment: Of course. A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is an abelian group.

Answer (score 2):

Any basis for $\Bbb C$ as a $\Bbb Q$ vector space must be infinite, since any finite dimensional $\Bbb Q$ vector space is countable, but $\Bbb C$ is not. Constructing such a basis requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Is above mentioned basis need any verification other than linear independency. Do we need axion of choice to say that above is a basis?

Comment: And what about my second question.(See the edited part) Thanks

Comment: @PittHarmanN-FreshmaN The axiom of choice is required to prove that every infinite dimensional vector space has a basis. Briefly, we partially order linearly independent sets by inclusion, and then invoke Zorn's Lemma.