# How do you find a basis for $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, cyclotomic-fields

In the comments on a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110015/do-there-exist-functions-satisfying-this-property) I posted earlier it was recommended that I find a basis for $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. How should I go about this? What would be a good reference for this?

Comment: The statement that any vector space (over a field) has a basis is essentially the axiom of choice. In this case, $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ of *uncountably infinite* dimension, so it's not as though you explicitly find one --- this isn't possible.

Comment: To add to David's comment, see this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594975/basis-of-vector-space-bbb-c-over-rational-numbers

Comment: @davidlowryduda thanks for the comment. Feel free to make it an answer and I'll accept since I doubt this question will have a better answer.

Comment: @HiMatt Thanks for the link!